# Why my asp.net MODAL doesn't display data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, modalpopupextender

I am trying to display a gridview inside ajax MODAL but it doesn't show the gridview. It shows every other element that I put INSIDE it but not a gridivew. 
I tried to display gridview outside the modal and it works but not inside modal. 
Why ?

Code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLastHearingDates" CssClass="modalPopup" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Visible="true">
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdViewLastHearingDates" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="grdViewLastHearingDates_PageIndexChanging"
               OnRowCommand="grdViewLastHearingDates_RowCommand" PagerStyle-BackColor="#99CC99" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CC99" DataKeyNames="pk_Cases_CaseID" PagerStyle-Font-Size="12.5px" PagerStyle-ForeColor="Black" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="grdViewLastHearingDates_RowEditing"
               CssClass="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
   <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pk_Cases_CaseID" HeaderText="Case ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CaseNo" HeaderText="Case No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NextHearingDate" HeaderText="Next Hearing Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DaysRemaining" HeaderText="Days Remaining" />
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Button ID="btnShowLasthearingDates" runat="server" OnClick="btnShowLasthearingDates_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlLastHearingDates" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowLasthearingDates" PopupControlID="pnlLastHearingDates">
```

.cs code:

```
protected void btnShowLasthearingDates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowLastHearingDates();
        pnlLastHearingDates.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Check in the console of Inspect Element if there is an error or not.

Comment: ok sir, let me check

Comment: Check if the HTML content is generated for the GridView inside the Panel, from the Inspect Element.

Comment: no sir, just an empty div

Comment: oh yes, the proble is figured out, btnShowLasthearingDates_Click event is not getting called, i check in debugging

Comment: the event onClick should call btnShowLasthearingDates but it doesn't.

Comment: Try adding `CausesValidation="False"` to your button.

Comment: tried sir, not working

Comment: After clickling, does it postback or stays as it is ?

Comment: Check on your Javascripts for any `false` returns. If any script is returning false, then it wont postback. Also, `keep CausesValidation="False"` as it is and close your script tags like this : `<script></script>` instead of `<script ... />`

Comment: sir when i remove button from Modal's targetcontrolID then button works otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is probably with the `TargetControlId` attribute of the `ModalPopupExtender`.

Try removing the Button ID from there and instead take a Hidden Field control in your aspx page and give it an ID. Now put that ID into the `TargetControlId` attribute and try clicking your button.

Your code would look like this :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HdnFld1" runat="server" />
                                        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BehaviorID="MPE" runat="server"
                                            CancelControlID="btnCancel"
                                            TargetControlID="HdnFld1" PopupControlID="Panel1"
                                            PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" Drag="true"
                                            BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
                                        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Also, you can keep `CausesValidation="false"` for your button just in case it stops postback due to validation, but again, you might handle it since that would postback without any kind of data checks on the client side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh great, it worked sir but I am wondering that how did it work ? A label is nor getting clicked nor getting executed but still it worked

Comment: Basically, you needed to add up a dummy control for it and replace the button with the control's ID. That's what was needed to make it work. So now, your popup has a target that does nothing and hence everything works as expected.